# Python-ldap Authentication doesn't need password

Tags: python-3.x, python-ldap

I have been researching on how to implement an authentication using python-ldap. Upon trying some codes and reading the documentation I've come up with the code below, upon testing, it always return "Invalid creds" when I input my password. But, it returns True whenever I leave my password blank.

```
import ldap, sys
 
secret = ''
un = 'xxx.x.xxxx'
 
server = "ldap://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx"
    
base = "dc=xxx,dc=xxx"
 
def checkUser():
    try:
        l = ldap.initialize(server)
        l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
        l.protocol_version = 3
        rex = l.simple_bind_s(un, secret)
        print(rex)
        return True
    except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
        print("Invalid creds")
        return False
    except ldap.SERVER_DOWN:
        print("Server down")
        return False
    except ldap.LDAPError as e:
        print(f"Error {e}")
        return False
    finally:
        l.unbind_s()
 
x = checkUser()
print(x)
```

Note: the account I am entering is just a normal user with no admin privileges.